# How to override “Copy” label with my custom label "Highlight" to menu options while selecting a text

Tags: java, android, ios, react-native

I have a some Text in react native. By default after select text the following options appear: "Copy", "Share" and "Select All". I need to change "Copy" label with my custom label "Highlight" with action copy to clipboard. In React native I can't find how to do that. How can I do this with java for Android or swift for IOS?

[image]
[image]